# Return values in C programming

Tags: c

1. I want the program to keep running till I choose to close it and clear the screen each time you convert a number(done)
2. The problem i have in this current code is that..if i press the 1st option i get the correct result..but if i press the same option or any other option it keep adding things up...for example...option 1. dec-bin. 10=1010. after that the program keeps running and if i choose the same option i get the result..10=10101010

```c
switch(option)
{
   case 1: //if 1 is selected
        printf("\nEnter Decimal to convert to Binary:"); //Prints the message between quotes
        scanf("%d",&dec); //Reads the Decimal number
        num=dec;

        while(dec!=0)
        {
            rem=dec%2;
            bin=bin+rem*i;
            dec=dec/2;
            i=i*10;
        }

        printf("\nThe Binary number is: %d \n\n",bin); //Prints the converted number

        system("pause"); //Pauses program
        system("cls"); //Clears the screen
        return 0;
        break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for example...option 1. dec-bin. 10=1010. after that the program keeps running and if i choose the same option i get the result..10=10101010

you missed to reset *bin* and *i* so *bin* accumulates, the first time produces 1010 then you add ('append') again 1010 producing 10101010

do `bin = 0; i = 1;` before the `while(dec!=0) ...`

Additional remarks :

- you have a risk of overflow on *bin*, you can use a string you will print in the reverse order you filled it
- you need to check the user enter a valid number checking *scanf* returns 1

Comment: @AmartiasAisopos warning with the overflow (I edited my answer)

Comment: I am new at programming so every tip/help is accepted...thanks again